# Program never finds an item in an ArrayList, even though it is supposed to be there

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

My assignment was to create a program which reads the data from a text file and then stores the data in an `ArrayList`. Then the user can enter an integer and the program checks if the number is in the database. The program returns a statement stating whether or not the number is in the database. The text file consists of integers each on their own separate line and the first number represents the number of integers that are in the file.

When I run my program, I keep getting "x is not the database" even when I enter a number that I know IS in the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirectoryLookupApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   File read = new File("Data3.txt");
   Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(read);
   ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();

   while (dataFile.hasNextLine()) {
      temporary.add(dataFile.nextLine());
   }
   temporary.remove(0); //removes the first element of the list since that element represents how many numbers are in the file
   Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Database Server is Ready for Number Lookups!");
   int searchingFor = userInput.nextInt();
   while (userInput.hasNext()) {
      searchingFor = userInput.nextInt();
      for (int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i++) {
         if (temporary.contains(searchingFor)) {
            System.out.println("It exists in the database");
            break;
         }
         else {
            System.out.println("It is not in the database");
         }
     }
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out your variables to check they hold what you think they hold.

Comment: Could you post an example of the content of the file? It could help.

Comment: I'm not a java expert, but did you mean `temporary[i].contains(searchingFor)`?

Comment: Don't vandalize your own questions.  If you delete the code then the question and the answers makes ZERO sense to other people.

Answer (score 2):

Your `temporary` list contains `String`s, but in `temporary.contains(searchingFor)` you are checking if it contains an `int`. This can never return true.

Perhaps you should replace

```
int searchingFor = userInput.nextInt();
```

with

```
String searchingFor = userInput.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your temporary List is a List of Strings:

```
ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();
```

User input from System.in is read as an integer:

```
int searchingFor = userInput.nextInt();
```

And you are trying to check if a List of Strings contains an Integer. Java is not perl, it does not convert types.
Either modify your code so that the `temporary` List will contain `Integer` Objects, or read a `String` from `userInput`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as you are comparing two different variable types. Your ArrayList has String values and you are comparing searchingFor which is an integer value. This can be solved by either using String values or integer values.

I found another two issues in your code.

1. First input you get from the scanner is not checked with the database. You have to enter the second value to check.
2. You have to add the break in the else statement as well. Otherwise loop will continue.
   I resolved those issues in the following code.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   File read = new File("Data3.txt");
   Scanner dataFile = new Scanner(read);
   ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();

   while (dataFile.hasNextLine()) {
       temporary.add(dataFile.nextLine());
   }

   temporary.remove(0); //removes the first element of the list since that element represents how many numbers are in the file

   Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Database Server is Ready for Number Lookups!");

   String searchingFor = ""; 

   while (userInput.hasNext()) {
       searchingFor = userInput.nextLine();  // gets input 
       for (int i = 0; i < temporary.size(); i++) {
           if (temporary.contains(searchingFor)) {
               System.out.println("It exists in the database");
               break;
           } else {
               System.out.println("It is not in the database");
               break;  // added break point 
           }
       }

   }}
   ```